# Stored Proc : Sql server tables backup

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I need to loop list of tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
and for each table_name output i need to create a seperate new table with data.

```
Ex : SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_Name in 
('EMP','DEPT','SAL')
```

My Procedure should drop older table names if they exists  and create three new tables with systemdate appeneded from above results

```
drop BKP_<Table_Name>_* //*Drop Old tables which are one week older with 
systemdate <=(sysdate-7))
select * into BKP_<Table_Name>_<SYSTEMDATE> FROM <Table_Name> ;
```

could you please help

Comment: Aha. And what's the question?

Comment: Hi , I need Stored Procedure which looks to below results from query ie TABLE_NAME ( I shown only 3 tables as example)
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_Name in 
('EMP','DEPT','SAL')
TABLE_NAME 
------------------
EMP
DEPT
SAL

Need to drop older tables which are more than 7 days old and create new tables like below based on above tables list .
drop table BKP_EMP_20181225 ;
select * into BKP_EMP_20190129 from EMP;

Comment: Yes, OK, but what is the question here? What's the problem? Where do you have trouble writing such a procedure? Please show the code you already have and explain what's wrong with it and where you need help.

Comment: Dropping tables that are 7 days old? This screams of a design gone horribly wrong. This is very obvious [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What you really need help is redesigning your architecture so you are not constantly creating these date specific backup copies of data.

Comment: Sure , will add my code as well next time . thanks

Comment: @SeanLange - yep got your point ,tables which i m using dont have more than 50K rows . its small set of data .Everyweekend we are loading data through ETL ..This backup needed to reverse back data into table in case if something goes wrong on weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of the logic.

Some adjustments still can be done, like error handling, better logging or extra parameter to pass - a table list. But can be a start point for further steps

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE usp_BackupTable
@RetentionDays int = 7
AS 

DECLARE @_tbl sysname, @_schema sysname, @_sql_Backup VARCHAR(400), @_sql_Drop VARCHAR(400);


-- first part: create backups of listed tables
DECLARE ct CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN  ('ETLSettings')  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'


OPEN ct
FETCH NEXT FROM ct INTO @_schema, @_tbl

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN    
    SET @_sql_Backup = 'SELECT * INTO ['+@_schema+'].BKP_'+@_tbl+'_'+CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 112)+' FROM ['+@_schema+'].['+@_tbl+'] ;'
    EXEC (@_sql_Backup)
    PRINT 'Backup of table ' + @_tbl + ' has been created'
FETCH NEXT FROM ct INTO @_schema, @_tbl 
END

CLOSE ct
DEALLOCATE ct


-- second part: cleanup of backups
DECLARE ct CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'BKP%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TRY_CAST(RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, 8) AS DATETIME ) < CAST(GETDATE()-@RetentionDays AS DATE)

OPEN ct
FETCH NEXT FROM ct INTO @_schema, @_tbl

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN    
    SET @_sql_Drop = 'DROP TABLE ['+@_schema+'].['+@_tbl+'] ;'
    EXEC (@_sql_Drop)

    PRINT 'Table ' + @_tbl + ' has been deleted'
FETCH NEXT FROM ct INTO @_schema, @_tbl 
END

CLOSE ct
DEALLOCATE ct
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander , it will work . i was looking for using one cursor with create and drop logic in it . this approach also fine for me

Comment: @Sumanth, yw, with one cursor the logic going to be more complicated, since you have a chance of few table backups to remove, then you need to nest cursors, therefore, imho simpler solution is to split logic into two separate pieces